# Mysql using join to print out totals for individual groups

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to print out a listing of device groups and the total number of devices in each group. However, when I run the below query, it only returns one group with the total number of devices in that group.

So, I would appreciate someone being able to point out what I am doing wrong.

Thank you.

```
select
    distinct DG.DeviceGroupName as DeviceGroup,
    DG.DeviceGroupID as GroupID,
    DG.IsParent,
    DG.IsDynamic,
    count(distinct RN_DEVICE.DeviceID) as DeviceAmount

from RN_DEVICE
    join RN_DEVICE_GROUP_DEVICE_MAP DG_MAP
            on RN_DEVICE.DeviceID   = DG_MAP.DeviceID

    join (
            SELECT DeviceGroupName, DeviceGroupID, IsParent, IsDynamic
            FROM RN_DEVICE_GROUP
    ) as DG on DG.DeviceGroupID = DG_MAP.DeviceGroupID

where RN_DEVICE.ManagementStatus <> 2
and DG.IsParent <> 0
order by DG.DeviceGroupName
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I edited some sentences out, that are obsolete. It doesn't matter how much experience you have. You are stuck with a problem, that's why you're here. That's all. Also please avoid sentences like "<whatever> didn't work", cause these don't help to understand the problem, when you don't post exact error messages or at least what you mean with "didn't work". When asking questions about SQL, it's almost always a good idea to include sample data and desired result. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `GROUP BY` clause.

Write the statement like this:

```
SELECT
    DG.DeviceGroupName as DeviceGroup,
    DG.DeviceGroupID as GroupID,
    DG.IsParent,
    DG.IsDynamic,
    COUNT(distinct RN_DEVICE.DeviceID) as DeviceAmount
FROM 
    RN_DEVICE
    JOIN RN_DEVICE_GROUP_DEVICE_MAP AS DG_MAP ON RN_DEVICE.DeviceID = DG_MAP.DeviceID
    JOIN RN_DEVICE_GROUP AS DG ON DG.DeviceGroupID = DG_MAP.DeviceGroupID
WHERE 
    RN_DEVICE.ManagementStatus <> 2
    AND DG.IsParent <> 0
GROUP BY 
    DG.DeviceGroupName,
    DG.DeviceGroupID,
    DG.IsParent,
    DG.IsDynamic
```

I removed the `DISTINCT` since it's obsolete when you do a `GROUP BY`.
The difference between `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` is, that `DISTINCT` removes duplicate rows (yes, it works on the entire row, not just one column) and `GROUP BY` kind of "collapses" rows. So it kind of has the same effect.

But, that's also why I have included so much columns in the `GROUP BY` clause. MySQL allows to write only one column in the `GROUP BY` clause, but selecting more. This is wrong and regularly confuses beginners. (That's also why this will be changed in future versions).

You always have to name every column in the `GROUP BY` clause, that you're also using in the `SELECT` clause, except those, that you're applying an aggregate function on. If you don't do this, a **random** row out of each group will be displayed!

I also removed the subquery in the `FROM` clause, simply because it's unnecessary :)

Comment: Great, your answer was right on, of course you knew that and thanks for the explanation. Can you provide a site that can help bring me up to speed on MySQL queries. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, not from the top of my head. I got up to speed through my job and stackoverflow :) If this issue is solved however, feel free to accept my answer by clicking the check to the left of my answer.